# Ember.js linking application to real api after mirage success

Tags: javascript, ember.js

As I'm going deeper and deeper into Ember.js application building process I hit another wall.

Before I was using mirage with great success - I just copy output from API that I wanted build around to mirage fixtures and it was working great.

Now I have problem with making it work with real API.

I first disabled mirage in config/environment.js

`ember g adapter filter`

```
import ApplicationAdapter from './application';
export default ApplicationAdapter.extend({
    findAll: function(store, type, label) {
        var url = `${this.host}/${this.namespace}/${type.modelName}`;
        console.log(`${url}`);
        return this.ajax(url, 'GET');
    },
});
```

The application adapter looks like this

```
import DS from 'ember-data';

export default DS.JSONAPIAdapter.extend({
    host: 'http://127.0.0.1:1234',
    namespace: 'api',

    headers: Ember.computed(function(){
        return {"secret": "1234"};
    })
});
```

And that way when I enter /filter 
`app/routes/filter/index`

```
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Route.extend({
        model() {
                    return this.store.findAll('filter');

        }
});
```

I can see that url is build ok as `http://127.0.0.1:1234/api/filter` and there is no 404 but I get error

`Error while processing route: filter.index The adapter operation was aborted EmberError@http://127.0.0.1:4200/assets/vendor.js:29616:15`

and as I don't fully grasp the know-how of Ember Inspector im trying to figure this out somehow

My filter model that worked before (with mirage) looks like this:

```
import DS from 'ember-data';

export default DS.Model.extend({
        name: DS.attr(),
        url: DS.attr()
});
```

The api returns list `[{"id":1, "name": "namex", "url": "http://"},{"id":2, "name": "namey", "url": "http://"}]`

I'm sure If its the way api return data as its not "filters" as I had problem with plurals before.

Edit: THIS RESOLVE THe problem

```
import DS from 'ember-data';

export default DS.RESTSerializer.extend(
{
        normalizeFindAllResponse(store, type, payload) 
        {
                var data = [];
                payload.forEach(
                    function(item, index, enumerable) 
                    {
                        var ob = {};
                        Ember.set(ob, 'id', item.id);
                        Ember.set(ob, 'type', 'filter');
                        Ember.set(ob, 'attributes', item);
                        data[index]=ob;
                        console.log(data[index]);
                    }
                );
                return {
                        data: data
                };
        }
});
```

This is almost the fix but not quite.
I can access some of model attributes like name, but there is a array object with 3 arrays inside, 2 of them are array the one in middle is Getter (what ever is that) and I cannot access it as its not array anymore. So im not sure if it binding to object correctly this way. Also I wasn't able to do anything with "data" because no matter what RESTAdapter here and there I put it would ignore it and ask for object with data/meta/errors attribute... dunno if its a bug or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you are using `JSONAPIAdapter` your api response should follow the JSON format specification.

```
{      
  "data": [{
    "type": "filter",
    "id": "1",
    "attributes": {
      "name": "namex",
      "url": "http://"    
    }
  }, {
    "type": "filter",
    "id": "2",
    "attributes": {
      "name": "namey",
      "url": "http://"
    }
  }]
}
```

or if you are not following JSONAPI in that case either you can change application adapter to extend `RESTAdapter`.

```
import DS from 'ember-data';

export default DS.RESTAdapter.extend({
    host: 'http://127.0.0.1:1234',
    namespace: 'api',

    headers: Ember.computed(function(){
        return {"secret": "1234"};
    })
});
```

RESTAdapter response would be like,

```
{"filters":[{"id":1, "name": "namex", "url": "http://"},{"id":2, "name": "namey", "url": "http://"}]}
```

either you need to send it like above format or manipulate it to produce the required format.(override [normalizeFindAllResponse](http://emberjs.com/api/data/classes/DS.RESTSerializer.html#method_normalizeFindAllResponse))

Comment: I change adapter to RESTAdapter as you suggested as Im unable to change api output, but that didn't helped. Still same error about aborting. Do I need to manipulate somehow data from api ? or is there some kind of force binding ?

Comment: Updated my answer . Usually `{"fitlers":[{}]}` will come but in your case you overrided findAll so you may be try with `{"fitler":[{}]}`

Comment: Only problem I have is that if i set ```export default ApplicationSerializer.extend({
normalizeFindAllResponse(store, type, payload) { return {data:payload};}``` I have error telling me that there need to be 'data' 'error' or 'meta' atribute as it want the structure you post for jsonapi which i change in adapters/application.js as you wrote .

Comment: I haven't done this before, but you need to ensure that `normalizeFindAllResponse` should return exact format. currently for json-api your code wont workout. but for RESTAPI your code might work if you `return {'data':payload}` and also ensure application serializer should extend `RESTSerializer`.

Comment: its return { filters : payload } as the payload is array of objects

Comment: ok then RESTAdapter will work.if not, we are missing something. let's hope some one will enlighten us. I hope you will solve it.

Comment: I added app/serializers/filter.js to question post. Im almost there but not yet.

Comment: In your updated code can you try this ` payload = { data: data};  return this._super(store, primaryModelClass, payload, id, requestType);`

Comment: as your sugestion and help gave me a right direction I marked your post as answer. thanks the coded I added in edit resolve my problem as the getter setter is just there but there is a data under it when you query for it.